# Swift 4 - Ambigous reference to member '>' (iOS 11)

Tags: ios, realm, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I am getting this misleading error message after converting to Swift 4 syntax.

> Ambiguous reference to member '>'

on this line of code :

```
redCount = alerts!.filter { $0.dangerLevels.filter { $0.level.value == 4 }.count > 0 }.count
```

full context code :

```
alerts = realm.objects(Alerts).filter(NSPredicate(format: "department != nil")).sorted(byKeyPath: "departmentNumber")

redCount = alerts!.filter { $0.dangerLevels.filter { $0.level.value == 4 }.count > 0 }.count
```

The error message isn't explicit at all, can I have some hints ?

Keep in mind that **alerts** is of type `Results<Alert>?`

and **dangerLevel** is declared as following: `let dangerLevels = List<DangerLevel>()`

**EDIT:**

Here are some additional informations concerning the types inside the closure.

```
let level = RealmOptional<Int>()
```

and value is from RealmOptional

```
public var value: T? {
        get {
            return underlyingValue.map(dynamicBridgeCast)
        }
        set {
            underlyingValue = newValue.map(dynamicBridgeCast)
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** I have rewritten the syntax for better readability but here are my results :

```
redCount = alerts!.filter { $0.dangerLevels.contains { ($0.level.value as! Int) == 4 } }.count
```

[image]

Comment: Please, use `!.object.isEmpty` instead of `count > 0` and `contains()` instead of `.filter().count > 0`.

Comment: In short: `redCount = alerts!.filter { $0.dangerLevels.contains { $0.level.value == 4 } }.count` will probably fix your problem. Also, I would recommend to sort after filtering and also use `alerts ?? []` instead of `alerts!`.

Comment: Now I got the ambiguous reference to member '=='.
Can you write an answer so that I can accept it if it works?

Comment: the crucial problem is probably connected to types, please show us what `value` is.  The compiler probably has problems to infer the type of the inner closure.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` is a generic method and when comparing with a literal (that is, something without a defined type), the compiler has a problem to figure out what type to infer there. One workaround is to add `as Int` to one side of the expression:

(slightly rewritten for readability)

```
let alerts = realm.objects(Alerts).filter(NSPredicate(format: "department != nil")).sorted(byKeyPath: "departmentNumber")

let isRedLevel: (DangerLevel) -> Bool = { dangerLevel in
   ($0.level.value as Int) == 4
}
let hasRedLevels: (Alert) -> Bool = { alert in
    alert.dangerLevels.contains(where: isRedLevel)
}

redCount = alerts!.filter(hasRedLevels).count
```

What would also work is to define a constant:

```
let redAlertType: Int = 4
```

and use it instead of the literal `4`.

Comment: Humm.. I am trying to rewrite it like you for better readability, but I got "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '((DangerLevel) -> Bool).Type'" at the isRedLevel line and Cannot convert value of type '(Alerts) -> Bool' to closure result type 'Bool' on the last line.

Comment: @BitoQ I did a mistake with `=` and `:` Try it now please.

Comment: I am not really sure if the type of `hasRedLevels` should take `Alert` or `Alerts`.

Comment: Alert. But I am getting confused with all this change with Realm. It's becoming kind of heavy... I got "Cannot convert value of type '(Alert) -> Bool' to closure result type 'Bool'" on the last line. But also "Value of type 'Results<Alert>' has no member 'dangerLevels'", but in my class Alert I have a let dangerLevels = List<DangerLevel>()

Comment: @BitoQ Maybe I did some mistakes in my rewriting. The `as Int` should fix the problem in your original code anyway. I see the error now. Sorry, writing without a compiler.

Comment: I thought your solution worked but my compiler was just slow showing me the error. The as Int solution isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, because I can't seem to use properly the Results<> and List<> types from Realm after converting my code to actual Swift Syntax (this is an old project written in Swift 2).

I simply use an Array.

```
let alerts = realm.objects(Alerts).filter(NSPredicate(format: "department != nil")).sorted(byKeyPath: "departmentNumber")
let alertArray = Array(alerts!)
```

And now I can filter properly on this type :

```
redCount = alertArray.filter { $0.dangerLevels.filter { $0.level.value == 4 }.count > 0 }.count
```

It finally compiles and works properly.

Feel free to propose an edit to a more modern Swift Syntax and/or appropriate answer.

*Thank you @Sulthan for your help and advices in the comments.*